# cannot get the last id in room database in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i'am trying to get the last id from room after insert to the table by get the max id and make it as liveData to observe it later

like this in dao :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insert(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) : Long

@Query("SELECT Max(Id) From Spends")
fun lastId() : LiveData<Long>
```

and the repo :

```
private var id : Long = -1
private var mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Long>()

suspend fun insert(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
    id = database.getAddSpendDao().insert(addSpendEntity)
    Log.e("addspendrepository",id.toString())
    mutableLiveData.value = id
    Log.e("addspendrepositoryid",mutableLiveData.value.toString())
}

fun getLastId() : LiveData<Long>
{
    return database.getAddSpendDao().lastId()
}
```

i know that i can get the last id by make insert fun return a long but because the insert fun is a suspend fun so the main thread cannot get the id from insert fun , so i decide to get the max id from the entity that i have and make insert fun return a long value to check if i get the correct id

the problem is when i observe the max id. the obersver show the previous state(id) of inserter like [image]

and the observer in fragment :

```
val addSpendEntity = AddSpendEntity(totalMoney,notice,date)
    addSpendViewModel.insertSpend(addSpendEntity)
    addSpendViewModel.addSpendLastId.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        Log.e("addspend",it.toString())
    })
```

and in viewmodel :

```
fun insertSpend(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
    addSpendRepository.insert(addSpendEntity)
}

val addSpendLastId = addSpendRepository.getLastId()
```

so why that happen for observer and what i should do to solve this problem

Comment: Why couldn't you get the ID when inserting it? You just have to come back to the main thread with another coroutine. Also, your screenshot doesn't actually show the issue (`addspend` is not included).

Comment: you mean get add withContext to the insert fun in repo to launch the coroutine

Comment: Yes, you can come back to the main thread with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` inside a coroutine

Comment: i try with that but it didn't work